# how to calculate an every process separately and display them at together at running time?

Tags: android, gps, distance

```
 b.putFloat("My Odometer", (float) (gpsdataElements.Distance-Contsants.jobStartKm));
                if(gpsdataElements.Speed<1)
                {
                    Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec++;
                }
                float totalKm =  Contsants.jobEndKm-Contsants.jobStartKm ;

                if (totalKm<Contsants.minDist)
                {
                    float totalfare=Contsants.minFare;
                    b.putString("Fare", String.format("%.2f",(totalfare)));
                }
                else
                {
                    float totalfare= Contsants.minFare+ ((totalKm-Contsants.minDist) *Contsants.rupeeKm)  +(Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec/60)*1;
                    b.putString("Fare", String.format("%.2f",(totalfare)));
                }
```

here is my code for calculating total fare. problem in else part condition. During running time it will not display the calculation properly. It was hangs up and shows force close error. any other way to calculate this (Contsants.minFare+ ((totalKm-Contsants.minDist) *Contsants.rupeeKm)  +(Contsants.cont_WaitingTimeInSec/60)*1) three parameters separately and display them together at running time. Because i am going to use this code for taxi booking application. i want to display the current fare in the display at running time.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy there is no error. but i want to calculate this process separately and add it together to total fare thats all. so i want some other way to do this process.

Comment: You said "It was hangs up and show force close error"?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy ya but it is showed in mobile. but i dont know how to copy that error from mobile.

Comment: @LawrenceChoy i dont know why that error came. I made my calculation exactly. any idea regarding this calculation process means please give me.